# Signal a QTreeWidgetItem toggled checkbox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots, qtreewidget

[How do I check if a checkbox is checked or unchecked? (In QTreeWidget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477625/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-unchecked-in-qtreewidget?rq=1) shows how to get the status of the checkbox on a qtreewidget item.  Using that method, with a signal for itemClicked in the Tree, I can query if the selected item is checked or not.  However, I then need to keep track of this item to see if it was previously checked or not.

Is there a method for knowing that a QTreeWidgetItem, which may be at different levels from the parent items, has a toggled checkbox, without making a subclass for it?

As a note, is there a specific reason the toggled method is not attached to the QTreeWidgetItem in QT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `itemClicked` signal is not a good choice for handling treewidget checkboxes.

On the one hand, it gives false positives when not clicking on the checkbox part of an item; and on the other hand, it gives false negatives when the checkbox is toggled using the keyboard.

I think the best that can be done with the existing signals, is to use [itemChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged). This will register all checkbox state changes made with both keyboard and mouse. It is not the perfect *general* solution, though, because it will give false positives whenever any other item data is changed (e.g. text, font, background colour, etc). So you would need to [block](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#blockSignals) the `itemChanged` signal whenever those other types of changes were made.

Comment: do you have any idea why there has not been an implementation of toggled for qtreewidget?

Comment: @user1938107. I suppose it's because `QTreeWidget` is a convenience class, and so there will be a lots of functionality that people *might* legitimately want, but that will never be added. In this particular case, though, I think it was a mistake not to include the data role when sending the `itemChanged` signal. Then again, you can always easily work around these kinds of issues by subclassing `QTreeWidgetItem` (or `QTreeView`).